# The identity function

Tags: general-topology, continuity, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

Can you help me to prove:

> **1:The ideal $(i, | i |)$is not principal.**($i$ is identity function)

[ If  $(i, | i |) = (d)$, there exists $g, h \in C(\mathbb{R})$(the real Continuous functions ) so that $i =gd$ and $
|i| = hd$ .It follows that $
g(0) = h(0) =0 $,morever there exist $s, t \in C(\mathbb{R})$ so that $ si + t |i| = d$. this implies that $ sg + th = 1$(constant function), a contradiction.]

> **2:Exhibite a principal ideal containing $(i, | i |)$**.

Comment: The ambient space is supposed to be the ring $C(\mathbb{R})$ of real continuous functions?

Comment: What’s wrong with the proof sketch you already gave after 1?